# Limit to zero of a definite integral (a solution to check)

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

It has been a while since I did limit calculations. My message here is to check if my reasoning is correct and if not, to hear from your possible solution.

I would like to evaluate the following limit (I could replace "$0$" by $0^{+}$ I guess):

$\mathrm{lim}_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{a} f(x,z,t) dz}{a}$, $\ \ \ \ \ (Eq. 1) $

where $a \ge 0$ and $f(x,z,t)$ is a real-valued continuous function of space $(x,z)$ and time $t$. Physically, $f(x,z,t)$ could represent the solution of a PDE like the heat equation.

To evaluate the limit given by Eq. (1), I used the L'Hospital's Rule ($H$) and derive the numerator and denominator of Eq. (1) with respect to $a,$ to obtain

$\mathrm{lim}_{a\rightarrow 0} \left[ \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a} f(x,z,t) dz \right] =^{H} \mathrm{lim}_{a\rightarrow 0}  \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{0}^{a} f(x,z,t) dz \right] = \mathrm{lim}_{a\rightarrow 0}  \frac{\partial}{\partial a}[F(x,z,t)]_{0}^{a} = \mathrm{lim}_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} F(x, z=a,t)$,  $\ \ \ \ (Eq. 2)$

where $F(x,z,t)$ is the corresponding primitive. Since
$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}[F(x,z=a,t)] \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial z}[F(x,z,t)]\bigg|_{z=a}$, we deduce that
$\mathrm{lim}_{a\rightarrow 0} \left[ \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a} f(x,z,t) dz \right] = \mathrm{lim}_{a\rightarrow 0} f(x, z = a, t), \ \  Eq. (3)$

by definition of the primitive.

Can you please tell me if $Eq. (2)$ as well as the provided solution $Eq. (3)$ are correct?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Looks right to me under the assumption that $f$ be continuous. You might come around the same result easily by applying the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks, it is edited! It is definitely continuous in my case. I am interested in the mean value theorem approach, but I am not sure how to apply it. If you can give me some insights, It would be nice!

Comment: If $x$ and $t$ are just parameters, then this is just the fundamental theorem of calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, then by the mean value theorem there exists $c \in [0,a]$ such that $f(x,c,t)=\frac{\int_0^a f(x,z,t)dz}{a}$.
Then also by continuity $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_0^a f(x,z,t)dz}{a}=\lim_{c \rightarrow 0} f(x,c,t)=f(x,0,t)$

Comment: Observe that the mean value theorem is in its one dimensional version since your integral is not multiple.

Comment: It is indeed faster! Thank you for your remark.

Comment: Glad you appreciate it. An accepted answer would be very nice too. :) Cheers mate!